# How can I access my Azure Sql Database when internet is down?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Let's say I have a C# WPF application connected with Azure SQL database, everything works fine and my queries work well. The only issue is when sometimes the internet is down, it cannot connect with the database and shows an error at the connection string (which is pretty obvious).

Is there any way I can alter my connection string to connect with the database offline, at least be able to view the data, given when the internet is back, the updates are sent to the Azure portal as well (preferably automatic but manual will work). Through some research, I was able to get something as Sync my database with others option in the Azure portal. What else can I do?

Comment: Without internet, any cloud services would be hard to use. But, you should implement retry logic in your application which would, if any troubles occour, perform a retry operation x-number of times before establishing that the internet is actually down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) to synchronize your Azure SQL Database (hub database) to a local SQL Server instance (member database) that can be a SQL Server Express Edition. You can configure bi-directional synchronization between them.

Whenever your Internet connection is down you can set your application to use the member database. Once the Internet connection is available SQL Data Sync will update the hub database with all the changes you made to the database while working offline..

Learn how to start using SQL Data Sync [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync).